# Actionbarsherlock - Title not displaying

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I've seen a few posts about getting the title to show in actionbarsherlock along with the icon. The icon is displaying fine, but the title does not show beside it.

Currently it shows the home icon with all the tabs beside it. What I am looking for is the home icon, then title, and below all this have the tabs show. Here is my code.

**ACTIVITY**

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mJsonHandler = JsonHandler.getInstance(this);
    }

 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();

        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();

        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

        ab.setTitle("TITLE TO SHOW");

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);     
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_item0:

            break;
        case R.id.menu_item1:

            break;
        case R.id.menu_item2:

            break;
        case R.id.menu_item3:

            break;
        case R.id.menu_item4:

            break;
        case R.id.menu_item5:

            break;
        default:
            this.onBackPressed();
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml (for menu)**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item0"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/menu_item0"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item1"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/menu_item1"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item2"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/menu_item2"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item3"
    android:orderInCategory="4"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/menu_item3"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item4"
    android:orderInCategory="5"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/menu_item4"/>

 <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item5"
    android:orderInCategory="6"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/menu_item5"/>
```

**Manifest**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Sherlock.Theme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

**Sherlock Theme**

```
<style name="Sherlock.Theme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar"> 
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried just calling setTitle("blah"); instead of ab.setTitle("foo"); ?

Comment: @dymmeh The title still does not show using just setTitle("") without getting the actionbar first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting too many menu items to `always` show in the `ActionBar`. You should only set the most important ones to do so. You should read through the Android Design Guidelines on the appropriate way to set up the `ActionBar`

[Android Design Guidelines - Action Bar organization](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html#organization)

Also, you should set up the `ActionBar` in `onCreate` and leave `onCreateOptionsMenu` for only inflating your menu(s). This is just a general tip and goes towards better, more professional code formatting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. I reduced the number to 2 items (to test) and the title shows, which is great. Unfortunately based on needs, all options need to show in the actionbar as well as the home and title above them (which they all fit without home/title). So is there a way to style actionbarsherlock such that the home icon and title are on one line and below them the icons show? I realize this is not part of guidelines since the home and title are considered items in the actionbar, but this is how it is requested to look.

Comment: What you're describing sounds like you want to use tabs instead of menu items. Look into that.

Comment: Tabs is definitely what I was looking for, there is an option in actionbarsherlock that I missed. To use tabs just need to set getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS); that way it has the actionbar on top and then the tabs below. Thanks for all the information and pointing me in the right direction.